# Conway's game of life - Optimizing the code

Tags: javascript, performance, game-of-life

I have just finished my first iteration of conway's game of life as a codeing excercise. I have little experience with coding, so I think my code could use some refactoring. What i am curios about is the drivers for having a more efficient code. My code is based on a cell object:

```
//Defining the cells  --------------------------------------------
function Cell (x,y,id, num) {
    this.id = id;
    this.num = num;
    this.isAlive = false;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.nextIsAlive = false;
    this.cellChange = false;
    this.cellTop = function() {
        if (this.y === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return getCell(this.x, this.y-OFFS-RECH/2).isAlive;

    };
    this.cellRight = function() {
        if (this.x+RECW >= canvas.width) {
            return false;
        }
        return getCell(this.x+RECW+OFFS+RECW/2, this.y).isAlive;

    };
    this.cellBottom = function() {
        if (this.y+RECH >= canvas.height) {
            return false;
        }
        return getCell(this.x, this.y+RECH+OFFS+RECH/2).isAlive;

    };
    this.cellLeft = function() {
        if (this.x === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return getCell(this.x-OFFS-RECW/2, this.y).isAlive;
    };

    this.cellUpperLeft = function() {
        if (this.x === 0 || this.y === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return getCell(this.x-OFFS-RECW/2, this.y-OFFS-RECH/2).isAlive;
    };

    this.cellUpperRight = function() {
        if (this.x+RECW >= canvas.width || this.y === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return getCell(this.x+RECW+OFFS+RECW/2, this.y-OFFS-RECH/2).isAlive;
    };

    this.cellBottomLeft = function() {
        if (this.x === 0 || this.y+RECH >= canvas.height) {
            return false;
        }
        return getCell(this.x-OFFS-RECW/2, this.y+RECH+OFFS+RECH/2).isAlive;
    };

    this.cellBottomRight = function() {
        if (this.x+RECW >= canvas.width || this.y+RECH >= canvas.height) {
            return false;
        }
        return getCell(this.x+RECW+OFFS+RECW/2, this.y+RECH+OFFS+RECH/2).isAlive;
    };

    this.numOfLiveNeighbour = function() {
        var i = 0;

        if (this.cellTop()) {
            i++;
        }
        if (this.cellRight()) {
            i++;
        }
        if (this.cellBottom()) {
            i++;
        }
        if (this.cellLeft()) {
            i++;
        }
        if (this.cellUpperLeft()) {
            i++;
        }
        if (this.cellUpperRight()) {
            i++;
        }
        if (this.cellBottomLeft()) {
            i++;
        }
        if (this.cellBottomRight()) {
            i++;
        }
        return i;

    };
}

Cell.prototype = {
    constructor: Cell,
    //Function where cell draws itself
    drawCell: function() {
        if (this.isAlive) {
            ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,RECW,RECH);
        } else {
            ctx.clearRect(this.x,this.y,RECW,RECH);
        }
    },
    //Function for killing a cell during animation
    killCell: function () {
        this.nextIsAlive = false;
    },
    //Function for reviving a cell during animation
    reviveCell: function () {
        this.nextIsAlive = true;
    },
    //function for turning on & off a cell when animation is not going.
    toggle: function() {
        if (this.isAlive) {
            this.isAlive = false;
        } else {
            this.isAlive = true;
        }
    }
};
// Cell finished -----------------------------------------------
```

As you can see i am trying to use a constructor/prototype pattern, but i think i have too many function definitions in the constructor, is that correct to assume? Is it a better way to do this?

I also have a suspicion that my functions for getting cells, determining next steps etc are not optimal:

```
//Function for finding a cell based on x & y coordinates ------------
function getCell(x,y) {
    for (var cell in cells) {
        var currCell = cells[cell];
        if (x >=currCell.x && x <= currCell.x+RECW && y >=currCell.y && y <= currCell.y+RECH) {
            return currCell;

         }

    }
}

//Function for drawing next step
function cellsNextStep() {
    var currCell;
    for (var cellNext in cells) {
        currCell = cells[cellNext];
        determineNextStep(currCell);
    }

    for (var cellDraw in cells) {
        currCell = cells[cellDraw];
        if (currCell.cellChange) {
            currCell.isAlive = currCell.nextIsAlive;
        }
        currCell.drawCell();
        currCell.cellChange = false;
        currCell.nextIsAlive = false;
    }
}

//Function for determining next value for each cell
function determineNextStep(cell) {
    var neighbours = cell.numOfLiveNeighbour();

    if (cell.isAlive) {
        if (neighbours < 2 || neighbours > 3) {
            cell.killCell();
            cell.cellChange = true;
        }

    } else {
        if (neighbours === 3) {
            cell.reviveCell();
            cell.cellChange = true;
        }
    }

}
```

My main problem is that when i try to increase the canvas size (number of cells are increased) the animation comes to a stand still. It is currently working ok with a canvas ov width 300, height 150 and cellsize of 7 (RECH and RECW) and offset between cells of 1 (OFFS).

I also have three different handlers, one for turning cells on and off before animation, one to start animation and one to stop. I guess I also should use one click handler on the document and make use of the bubble feature to only have one event handler (but i dont think that is my main performance issue here).

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `for ... in` loops on arrays in JavaScript. Use a numeric index and a plain `for` loop. Besides that, your performance problem stems from the fact that you have to **search** to find your cells. Keep track of them with an array of arrays (a 2-dimensional array, in other words) and your "getCell()" function will be **much** faster.

Comment: Yes, you can put all your methods on the prototype since they're using only properties of your objects, not the local variables (parameters) in your constructor.

Comment: For starters, run this through jslint or jshint.

Comment: @Pointy: thanks, the `for ... in` change helped alot. I also moved the functions to the prototype, but i didn't quite understand the change of the `getCell()` function. This function is based on the event from a mouseclick (using the x and y coordinates to determine the cell). Maybe it is smart to have one functions for this task and one "internal" getCell that keeps track of the cells?

Comment: @Øyvind well if you kept track of your cells in a data structure that allowed a direct lookup instead of a search, you'd save a huge amount of overhead.

Comment: Can you build a jsfiddle for this? I would love to play with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code could indeed probably use some tuning.

The three major points are:

- A cell should know it's neighbors, you should only **once** determine the neighbors for each cell and place them in an array in that Cell. This will speed up your code tremendously.
- Only living cells and their neighbors can change, tracking the living cells in a queue ( array ) will speed up your code. You would check the cells in that queue and the neighbors within the cells for changes.
- Checking all cells for life status changes in status slows the code down, you should have a queue ( array ) where you add all cells that change status. This way you only draw what changes.

Then there are some minor things you can consider:

1.

```
drawCell: function() {
    if (this.isAlive) {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,RECW,RECH);
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(this.x,this.y,RECW,RECH);
    }
```

this could be a little DRYer since the parameters are the same.

```
drawCell: function() {
  var action = this.isAlive ? ctx.fillRect : ctx.clearRect;
  action(this.x,this.y,RECW,RECH);
}
```

2.

```
toggle: function() {
    if (this.isAlive) {
        this.isAlive = false;
    } else {
        this.isAlive = true;
    }
}
```

could use some Boolean magic:

```
toggle: function() {
    this.isAlive = !this.isAlive;
}
```

Finally, `determineNextStep` should really be part of the `prototype` of `Cell`.